# parse xml node child in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

```
<item p4:stage="Ways and Means resolution" xmlns:p4="urn:services.parliament.uk-bills.ext"><guid isPermaLink="true">http://services.parliament.uk/bills/2013-14/antisocialbehaviourcrimeandpolicingbill.html</guid><link>http://services.parliament.uk/bills/2013-14/antisocialbehaviourcrimeandpolicingbill.html</link><category>Commons</category><category>Government Bill</category><title>Anti-social Behaviour, Crime and Policing</title><description>To make provision about anti-social behaviour, crime and disorder, including provision about recovery of possession of dwelling houses; to make provision amending the Dangerous Dogs Act 1991, Schedules 7 and 8 to the Terrorism Act 2000 and the Extradition Act 2003; to make provision about firearms and about forced marriage; to make provision about the police, the IndependentPolice Complaints Commission and the Serious Fraud Office; to make provision about criminal justice and court fees; and for connected purposes.</description><a10:updated>2013-06-05T17:42:59+01:00</a10:updated></item>
```

I can parse all thats within `<item></item>` using this:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var stage = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log(stage);
});
```

But I am looking at whats inside :

```
<item....>  for example,
```

I need to pull whats inside:

```
 <p4:stage></p4:stage>
```

How do I pull this out ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no `<p4:stage></p4:stage>` in that invalid XML, `p4:stage` is an attribute on the item element

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var p4 = $(this).attr('p4:stage');
    console.log(p4);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JEmfZ/)